# Skip text in RichTextBox

Tags: c#, text, newline, richtextbox

I would skip the text in the field, if there is no text, but if this is to add text to the beginning and the end. I'm trying like this but it add text every line.

```
    private void zmien(string a, string b)
    {


        {
            if (richTextBox1.Text.Length > 0)
            {
                string[] lines = richTextBox1.Lines;
                for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (richTextBox1.Text.Length == 0)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
                            lines[i] = Environment.NewLine;
                    }
                    else
                        lines[i] = a  + lines[i] + b;
                }
                richTextBox1.Lines = lines;
                //richTextBox1.SelectedText = "test" + lines;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: First change method name from "zmien" to Change. You have to use code convensions. And tell me one thing, because im not sure what you want achieve. You want set text on start and on the end of the text if  it exist in richTextBox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that much simply as you think, try follow this code

```
 private void zmien(string a, string b)
    {
            if (richTextBox1.Text.Length > 0)
            {
                richTextBox1.Text = a+" "+richTextBox1.Text+" "+b;
            }
     }
```